# Getting date and time from a .txt

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the date and time from a file I have which is something like this

```
"Run01"
"‹L˜^’·","ŽžŠÔŽ²","ÄØ¶Þ“ú•t","ÄØ¶ÞŽž"
"70000 DIV","100ms (1ms/S)","17-03-25","06:16:15.49"

"Á¬ÈÙ","±ÝÌß","“dˆ³Ž²","ºÒÝÄ","½¹°ØÝ¸Þ","•ÏŠ·”ä","µÌ¾¯Ä","Ì¨ÙÀ"
"CH1-1","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector11","OFF","-","-","OFF"
"CH1-2","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector12","OFF","-","-","OFF"
"CH2-1","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector21","OFF","-","-","OFF"
"CH2-2","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector22","OFF","-","-","OFF"
"CH3-1","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector31","OFF","-","-","OFF"
"CH3-2","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector32","OFF","-","-","OFF"
"CH4-1","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector41","OFF","-","-","OFF"
"CH4-2","8956 H-SPEED","200mV","Detector42","OFF","-","-","OFF"

"ŽžŠÔ[s]","CH1-1[V]","CH1-2[V]","CH2-1[V]","CH2-2[V]","CH3-1[V]","CH3-2[V]","CH4-1[V]","CH4-2[V]"
```

where the date and time is located in line 3 after the 2 comma(,)

I'm a bit confused from the examples found on google. Anyone have any idea on how I might do this?

edit*I add some bit of what I done so far,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

const int LINE = 4;

int draft(){
    std::ifstream fdate("DataFile0001/DataFile_B0001_info.txt");
    std::string s;

    for (int i = 1; i<= LINE; i++)
        std::getline(f,s);

    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

TO be honest I do not want to compile and run this but rather just `root draft.cc` as I am going to use it to process the root file I have. But as this is more of a c++ problem rather than root. asking here I think is more appropriate

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i<= LINE; i++)
{
    std::getline(f,s);

    if(i == 3)
    {
        size_t pos = s.find_first_of(",");
        pos = s.find_first_of("," , pos+1);

        std::string date = s.substr(pos+2 , s.find_first_of("," , pos+1)-pos-3);

        pos = s.find_first_of("," , pos+1);

        std::string time = s.substr(pos+2 , s.length()-pos-3);

        std::cout << date << std::endl;
        std::cout << time << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```